# Activating dictionary objects during import of new software is blocked in SAP ABAP

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I'm facing the following error while activating the **Field-Element-Domain** in **SE11**:

> Activating dictionary objects during import of new software is blocked

I am performing this operation with "test" user having `SAP_ALL` authorization in the development environment.

How to remove this error?

Answer (score 4):

this message appears when you are in the middle of a software import (like an upgrade or import of a support package). The import/upgrade modifies DDIC objects during one or several of its phases and manually activating objects can cause problems during the upgrade (up to rendering the system unusable). See [SAP note 2482243](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002482243) for more details.

it is a warning, not an error, so you could proceed with the activation. But you'd have to be absolutely sure you're not modifying an object that is part of the software import.